# Pathfinding algorithm - railroad interlocking

Tags: algorithm, graph, path

Given this interlocking diagram below, what algorithm do I need to find a (possibly shortest) permissible path between two points? I am interested in the theory, e.g. can Dijkstra handle this, does it have to be a directed graph, possibly other constraints ...
More context below.

[image]
The red pushbuttons define the start/end of a route, if it is valid*.
The green indicators, if lit, show any active route.
The yellow indicators, if lit, shows each switches' position.

*Definition "valid route": any number of switches a train must pass *without changing direction*, to reach its destination track.

Example shown above: A train enters on main track #200 and is to be moved to track #12, or the other way around.

**Invalid route example** (would require change in direction):
[image]

**Two valid routes** (green route favorable):
[image]

I had some exposure to Dijkstra in school, but this is way over my head.
Any pointers welcome.

Tl; DR: Questions:

- Which algorithm should I use?
- Edge weights?
- Directed edges?
- ...

Comment: dijkstra's works on either directed or undirected graphs (note that a bidirectional graph can be converted into a directed one) with non-negative edge weights

Comment: anyway this seems like more a DP/backtracking and recursion type problem than a pure graph problem

Comment: Dijkstra can be used, and will find exactly one path (guaranteed to be the shortest weight) between a source and destination if a valid route exists (otherwise the destination will be 'unreachable') given current switch states.  The edges should be directed (for example c->d is not a valid route, however d->c is valid).  The weights should reflect the travel time between nodes.  Dijkstra will also find the (shortest) weights to all nodes given a source.  Consider an 'all pairs' algorithm as well (like Floyd Warshall) if you prefer to know the shortest routes between any two points.